# Load balancing with ASP.NET and ADFS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, load-balancing, adfs

We're using ASP.NET MVC 5 with external authentication based on ADFS. Wea are using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule`.

Now we want to use a second instance. The load balancer uses an own cookie to identify a user and to enable sticky sessions.

The problem now is, that the user is not authenticated when a second instance is attached to the load balancer.

I think it is a configuration issue of ADFS. Is there any option which could occurs this error here? Or any other help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: `Microsoft.IdentityModel` uses Windows Data Protection API. This stored the token key inside the Windows DPAPI.
Problem: this cannot be synced with other machines because the encryption key is different on every machine.

You have to switch your provider to `Security.IdentiyModel`.

Comment: Could you point to some documentation on how to do this please?